# Mocking method call with out param and no return value in Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

So I've got this method called LoginUser:

```
public void LoginUser(out SystemUser userToLogin, string username)
```

Having just started with Rhino Mocks, I'm having a little trouble mocking a call and return value from this method while testing my Presenter code. What's the correct syntax in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [this blog post](http://www.cozcog.com/2009/07/rhino-mocks-out-ref-parameters.html) help? Code sample:

```
IList<RecordModel> ReadPaged(int pageNumber, int pageSize, out int recordCount);
...
recordRepositoryStub
 .Stub(m => m.ReadPaged(pageNumber, pageSize, out recordCount))
 .OutRef(250)
 .Return(records);
```

Basically, look for the `OutRef` method and use that to return the right result :)

As an aside, does your method *have* to be in that form? Using an out parameter in a void method is usually a bit of a design smell.

Comment: Thanks! 

I didn't write said code, but yes I was thinking I might petition to have it changed...